# Optional dependency in a Clojure library

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

My library, [Prerenderer](https://carouselapps.com/prerenderer), can work with or without [re-frame](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame), but when using re-frame, it requires 0.6.0 or later due to changes in re-frame. Is there a way to specify this requirement or do I have to break Prerenderer into two libraries, Prerenderer with the core and Prerenderer Re-frame with the Re-frame specific part?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specify what the minimum version of a dependency is, but you can put them into the `"provided"` scope:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.122"]
               [re-frame "0.6.0" :scope "provided"]]
```

Dependency resolution will not include transitive `"provided"` dependencies, so they have to be explicitly stated in whatever is using your library (which needs to be communicated in the README).

**Update:** As @Alex pointed out in the comments, you can add such dependencies to a profile called `:provided` instead.

Alternatively, you can put the `re-frame` dependency into your `:dev` profile which will make e.g. tests pass but not include the dependency in the `pom.xml` for artifact deployment.

Comment: I've always seen provided dependencies in leiningen specified using the `:provided` profile. Does `:scope` do the same thing?

Comment: @Alex I just tried it and while the position of the `<dependency>` tag in the POM changed, the contents (esp. `<scope>provided</scope>`) were the same. I'll update my answer to mention the `:provided` profile, thanks for the comment!